# How to decode data off spotify api

Tags: javascript, spotify

I successfully got the Spotify API to work with spotify-web-api-js, but I have no idea how to decode this. I want to be able display the title and artist of the song currently playing on a HTML page.

Right now to test, I'm trying to use `<script>document.getElementById("song").innerHTML = data.timestamp</script>` (`data` is the stuff from the Spotify api) to get the timestamp since I don't know what the format is to go deeper into the Spotify response. I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined`.

Note: I'm new to coding

Here's the javascript that gets the stuff from Spotify:

```
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-js');
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
var data;

spotifyApi.setAccessToken('token')
spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlayingTrack('title')
.then(function(data) {
    console.log('Now playing', data);
  }, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Here's the part of the html webpage that supposed to show the title of the song (in this case the timestamp, for testing purposes):

```
  <body>
      <div class=center>
        <h1 id="song"></h1>
        <h2>Luna Li</h2>
        <script>document.getElementById("song").innerHTML = data.timestamp</script>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Response from spotify:

```
{
  "timestamp" : 1592617721303,
  "context" : {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/3GU8BzFEAdFSRjc8jZkL3S"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3GU8BzFEAdFSRjc8jZkL3S",
    "type" : "album",
    "uri" : "spotify:album:3GU8BzFEAdFSRjc8jZkL3S"
  },
  "progress_ms" : 27470,
  "item" : {
    "album" : {
      "album_type" : "compilation",
      "artists" : [ {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0LyfQWJT6nXafLPZqxe9Of"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0LyfQWJT6nXafLPZqxe9Of",
        "id" : "0LyfQWJT6nXafLPZqxe9Of",
        "name" : "Various Artists",
        "type" : "artist",
        "uri" : "spotify:artist:0LyfQWJT6nXafLPZqxe9Of"
      } ],
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AE", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BH", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IL", "IN", "IS", "IT", "JO", "KW", "LB", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MA", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PS", "PT", "PY", "QA", "RO", "SA", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TH", "TN", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY", "VN", "ZA" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/3GU8BzFEAdFSRjc8jZkL3S"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3GU8BzFEAdFSRjc8jZkL3S",
      "id" : "3GU8BzFEAdFSRjc8jZkL3S",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2730bdf4dd39843ad48c5b66bc4",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e020bdf4dd39843ad48c5b66bc4",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d000048510bdf4dd39843ad48c5b66bc4",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "La La Land (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack)",
      "release_date" : "2016-12-09",
      "release_date_precision" : "day",
      "total_tracks" : 15,
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:3GU8BzFEAdFSRjc8jZkL3S"
    },
    "artists" : [ {
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6kXm2YCtdUOpRYNKeKhfue"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6kXm2YCtdUOpRYNKeKhfue",
      "id" : "6kXm2YCtdUOpRYNKeKhfue",
      "name" : "Ryan Gosling",
      "type" : "artist",
      "uri" : "spotify:artist:6kXm2YCtdUOpRYNKeKhfue"
    }, {
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/68Uwx1d3EbjDJhYsLjqvIq"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/68Uwx1d3EbjDJhYsLjqvIq",
      "id" : "68Uwx1d3EbjDJhYsLjqvIq",
      "name" : "Emma Stone",
      "type" : "artist",
      "uri" : "spotify:artist:68Uwx1d3EbjDJhYsLjqvIq"
    } ],
    "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AE", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BH", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IL", "IN", "IS", "IT", "JO", "KW", "LB", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MA", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PS", "PT", "PY", "QA", "RO", "SA", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TH", "TN", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY", "VN", "ZA" ],
    "disc_number" : 1,
    "duration_ms" : 236506,
    "explicit" : false,
    "external_ids" : {
      "isrc" : "USUG11600652"
    },
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/4r9hiElqKWMPT4Z3vN2exq"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4r9hiElqKWMPT4Z3vN2exq",
    "id" : "4r9hiElqKWMPT4Z3vN2exq",
    "is_local" : false,
    "name" : "A Lovely Night",
    "popularity" : 62,
    "preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/b315c0bd334edba2f571a4d5e1986ae544d8cf1b?cid=1f307ec00d7b4f3186cb56d56162cab6",
    "track_number" : 4,
    "type" : "track",
    "uri" : "spotify:track:4r9hiElqKWMPT4Z3vN2exq"
  },
  "currently_playing_type" : "track",
  "actions" : {
    "disallows" : {
      "resuming" : true
    }
  },
  "is_playing" : true
}
```

Is there an easy way to get the title of the song and artist from this? I feel like you could do it with `<script>document.getElementById("song").innerHTML = data.timestamp</script>` but I'm not sure how to navigate through the Spotify response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I was messing around and put `console.log(data.item.name)` and it successfully got the title of the song! For the HTML part, I had trouble getting the variables from the HTML, so I just moved the `document.getElementId("song")...` to the javascript!

Here's what the final script looks like:

```
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-js');
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
var data;

spotifyApi.setAccessToken('token');
spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlayingTrack('title')
.then(function(data) {
  console.log('Now playing', data);
  console.log(data.item.name)
  document.getElementById("song").innerHTML = data.item.name
}, function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

and the part of the HTML:

```
  <body>
      <div class=center>
        <h1 id="song"></h1>
        <h2>Luna Li</h2>
      </div>
  </body>
```

I'm not sure if I'm correct, but since I used [spotify-web-api-js](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js), it looks like it gave out the response as an object instead of a JSON.

Comment: Tip: You can also hover over a specific item in the console log in chrome and it'll show you what to put to filter it! I needed this since I didn't know I had to put the `[]` when I needed to filter an object (or array?) category with numbers. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/deLYd7x.png)